# Heroku app migrated to Europe cannot run under APPNAME.heroku.com

Tags: heroku, dns

I'm migrating an app which has been running for very long already under APPNAME.heroku.com to Europe. Unfortunately the app is also well known with customers as APPNAME.heroku.com

The new app now has the name APPNAME.herokupapp.com (note the 'app' after heroku) and I cannot add APPNAME.heroku.com to it (Could not add APPNAME.heroku.com. Can't add an additional Heroku domain.)

Is there anything I can do to keep the app running under APPNAME.heroku.com also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heroku.com is for the old Bamboo platform whilst the new Cedar platform which is the only one available in Europe uses herokuapp.com.

Your only option would be to replace the appname.heroku.com application with a redirect to the new appname.herokuapp.com version of the application...and then think about buying and mapping a custom domain to the application :)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up building a reverse proxypass thingy in Bamboo on the old heroku.com domain which gets the content from the eu app. (https://github.com/yukinoraru/heroku-http-reverse-proxy) .(And now I finally have a really good reason to tell the customer they never should use the old domain name again because that's quite slow now :-)